# Visualization issues with vim using Go-Global

Tags: bash, vim, remote-access

One of the new student in our lab is using her PC laptop to connect to our server using Go-Global for Unix v.2.3.0. There are two steps involved:

1. Opening a Xterm session in Go-Global gets her into a server accessible from outside of the school
2. She then `ssh` to our main server (step 1 is mandatory).

On the intermediate server, everything works just as expected. However, on the main server, we are experiencing some issues with Vim and its display. For example, if we go into insert mode, start typing something then erase it with backspace, the erased characters are still showing. I verified that the deleted characters that are still showing are indeed deleted by yanking and pasting the line somewhere else in the code. Also, after going out of insert mode, the `--- INSERT ---` sign at the bottom does not disappear.

The main server uses a `bash` shell and Vim version 7.4. The dummy server is using `tcsh` but I doubt this is related to the present issue.

Comment: this brings me back memories of vanilla vi on a serial TTY, that's why crtl.l was a good friend back then. Btw if it's VIM, set backspace=2, check that terminal is a valid one (e.g. xterm or vt100) and check if you need an stty erase ^H on the terminal. For the INSERT, set showmode should solve.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stty erase ^H". A google search told me `sttyl` is a command but I'm not sure what you want me to do with it.
Also, I am indeed using Xterm and I put `set backspace2=2` and `set showmode` in my `.vimrc` file but that did not help.

Comment: stty it's a command to issue on the terminal before running vim, set backspace not set backspace2. the set showmode isn't showing you the INSERT prompt ? mmm try adding also a set nocp in your .vimrc (and check it's actually executed).

Comment: So this morning, Vim seems to work as expected, even though we did not change anything... I will let you know if it stops behaving correctly again, thanks!